# Tablelayout in Scrollview not working

Tags: android, scrollview, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablelayout

My fragment loads its data into a tablelayout inside a scrollview.  At first, it will load saying "Click on image to view more data".
I have a onclick listener from the gallery that should delete all the rows from the tablelayout  with `tableLayout.removeAllViews();`.  Then the fragment will add row/rows to a tablelayout inside a scrollview.

The tablelayout should change on every click from the gallery.

However I am getting: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child.
This line shows up with the above error in logcat: `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` in my addToTracker function.

**gallery activity**

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity 
{
    private  Gallery[] galleryView;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Dish>> listOfList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        galleryView = new Gallery[3];

        //for each of the 3 sites
        galleryView[0] = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.galleryid0);
        galleryView[1] = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.galleryid1);
        galleryView[2] = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.galleryid2);

        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        galleryView[0].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                addToTracker(0, position, fragmentTransaction);
            }
        });

        galleryView[1].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                addToTracker(1, position, fragmentTransaction);
            }
        });

        galleryView[2].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                addToTracker(2, position, fragmentTransaction);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addToTracker(int id, int position, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
    {
            TrackerFragment tf = (TrackerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tracker1);
            fragmentTransaction.remove(tf);
            tf = TrackerFragment.newInstance(listOfList.get(id).get(position));

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tracker1, tf);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
   }
```

**tracker fragment**

```
public class TrackerFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Dish dish;

    public static TrackerFragment newInstance(Serializable dish) 
    {
        TrackerFragment tf = new TrackerFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("dish", dish);
        tf.setArguments(args);

        return tf;
    }

    public static TrackerFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle)
    {
        Dish dish = (Dish) bundle.getSerializable("dish");
        return newInstance(dish);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle myBundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(myBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracker, container, false);

        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tracker_layout);
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();

        if (dish != null)
        {   
            //display others

            //display subsystem stuff
            for (int i = 0; i < dish.getSubsystems().size(); i++)
            {
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(v.getContext());
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
                tv.setText(dish.getSubsystems().get(i).getConnFuncAddr());

                tableRow.addView(tv);

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(v.getContext());
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
            tv.setText("Click on image to view more data");

            tableRow.addView(tv);

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Trackers -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment 
            android:name="android.gallery.TrackerFragment"
            android:id="@+id/tracker1"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </fragment>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Gallery -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp">

            <Gallery 
                android:id="@+id/galleryid0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp">

            <Gallery 
                android:id="@+id/galleryid1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp">

            <Gallery 
                android:id="@+id/galleryid2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tracker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:text="Tracker 1" 
        android:id="@+id/t1"/>

      <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/delete2"
        android:onClick="remove1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t1" />

      <TableLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tracker_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/t1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">    

      </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?  I am guessing I am adding a table row to the scrollview and not the tablelayout, however, I dont see where I am doing that wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Create Tablelaout in this way




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">



      <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/data_table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
  </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am still getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child`. Also getting an error on this line: `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`