# Clickable table of contents

Tags: android

I am attempting to make a 'table of contents' that is similar in feel to [wikipedias as shown here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton)

I have a `ScrollView` which contains many `TextViews`. I have made a 'table of contents' that has clickable elements, but I cannot figure out how to make the `ScrollView` `scrollTo()` the right spot.

I attempted to convert the `TextView` to a string, and use `s.IndexOf()`, but it gives me the location of the text within the string, not within the `ScrollView`. This behavour makes sense

I then tried to look at other `ScrollView` methods to find something helpful, but ran out of ideas.

If I could find the `IndexOf` the `TextView` within the `ScrollView` I could easily `ScrollTo` that spot, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Thanks,
EDIT2: This is very similiar to hyperlinking to an inline anchor in HTML, using the # [as described here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

EDIT: added my XML, this would seem to be the only important part of the code to make it more clear. The goal is to hit the `TextView` with id `KeyQuestionsTextView` and have it scroll down to the `TextView` with id `KeyQuestions`. I have made the `onclick` listener for `KeyQuestionsTextView` register the `OnClick` event, but I do not know how to make the `ScrollView` scroll to the right spot. I really need to just get the Y offset of the desired `TextView` within the `ScrollView`, as the `ScrollTo` method is straightforward it seems.

The above example will be repeated for `PhysicalExamTextView` `DiagnosticReasoning` and `Emergencies`. Those four elements compose my 'table of contents'.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Platform2_option1" >



<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Plat2Option1Intro" />

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/KeyQuestionsTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/KeyQuestionsTitle" />
        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/PhysicalExamTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/PhysicalExamTitle" />
        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/DiagnosticReasoningTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/DiagnosticReasoningTitle" />
        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/EmergenciesTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/EmergenciesTitle" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/KeyQuestions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Plat2Option1KeyQuestions" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PhysicalExam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Plat2Option1PhysicalExam" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DiagnosticReasoning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Plat2Option1DiagReasoning" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Emergencies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Plat2Option1Emergencies" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution.First you get the Y axis of touch, when you click on a Textview like this,

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int y = (int)event.getY();

return false;
}
```

Then scroll your scroll view to that Y axis like,

```
YourScrollView.scrollTo(0, y);//here y is the y axis coordinate got from touch event
```

Comment: Currently the `ScrollView` has a `LinearLayout` inside it of. I did some quick searching about making that a `TableLayout` and found minimal positive results. Can anyone else chime in on if this may work before I head down that road?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585019/tablelayout-in-scrollview-not-working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861851/scrollview-doesnt-display-whole-tablelayout

Comment: With the 'table of contents' layout in Wikipedia that I am trying to emulate, you click on an item in the table of contents and it scrolls to that content. I am not sure how the above code would get me from the `OnClick` event to scroll to the new location.

The `OnClick` Event is triggered many many lines above the actual `TextView` I want to scroll to. 

I am unfamiliar with MotionEvents, and maybe somehow this could help  me 'index' the different `TextViews` I am hoping to navigate to, but I am not certain of this.

Comment: Can you post your code, so that your qstn will be more clear.

Comment: Added my XML file I am working with, not sure if that'll help or not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I found out that I could get the Y location of the `TextView` fairly easily and `ScrollTo` it fairly easily:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.KeyQuestionsTextView);
sv.scrollTo(0, (int) tv.getY());
```